# How can I compare the 2 variables in JavaScript to see if the dates are the same?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variables. How can I compare the 2 variables in JavaScript to see if the dates are the same? I don't want to conevert the 2 dates with time. i just want to convert them into yyyy/dd/mm format.

```
var DateReported = "20/04/2011";
var StartDate = "16/04/2011";
```

I have to do something if StartDate < DateReported and something else if StartDate > DateReported

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to convert them to check equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use conversion to date, try this(I assume the months and days are always 0 padded):

```
var DateReported = "20/04/2011"; 
var StartDate = "16/04/2011";
var regExp = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
if
(
    StartDate.replace(regExp, "$3$2$1") < DateReported.replace(regExp, "$3$2$1")
)
{
    alert("Lesser");
}
else
{
    alert("Greater");
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GE83j/

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dates stored as strings in the same date format, there's no reason why you can't you string comparison to check if they're equal:

```
var DateReported = "20/04/2011";
var StartDate = "16/04/2011";

return DateReported == StartDate;  // returns false;
```

**Update**: if you actually need to compare the dates to determine which is the most recent, I'd recommend making use of a library - e.g. the [jQuery UI module](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) contains date handling code, so you can easily parse date strings:

```
var dReported = $.datepicker.formatDate('d/mm/yy', DateReported);
var dStarted = $.datepicker.formatDate('d/mm/yy', StartDate);

if (dReported > dStarted) { ... }
```

Comment: but I have to do something if StartDate < DateReported and something else if StartDate > DateReported

Comment: that's not actually what you asked!

Comment: @Asif then you should clarify your question because it asks how to find if "the dates are the same?"

Answer (score 0):

by == operator

```
if(DateReported == StartDate)
return true;
```

else create the date object and convert them to millisecond and then compare for > / <

```
DateReported = new Date(2011,4,20);
StartDate= new Date(2011,4,16);

if (DateReported .getTime()<StartDate.getTime()) {
  alert('DateReported is less than StartDate');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var DateReported = "20/04/2011";
var StartDate = "16/04/2011";
DateReported = new Date(DateReported).format("yyyy/dd/MM");
StartDate = new Date(StartDate).format("yyyy/dd/MM");
if (DateReported > StartDate) {
     alert("Date Reported Greater");
}
else {
     alert("Start Date Greater");
}
```